# Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException:Element <defaultCache> does not allow attribute "maxEntriesLocalDisk"

Tags: java

I am trying to convert my application to maven.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

I changed various versions but still no use.I am new to maven. 
Please help me to figure out what am doing wrong.

Comment: Please Is the problem encountered while compilation, or dependency resolution.

Comment: when run the application, i could see

Comment: Add the error in the question, not in comments